# How to classify text pairs using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf, text-classification

I have read many different blogs on this topic, but haven't been able to find a clear solution. I have  the following scenario:

1. I have a list of pairs of texts with labels 1, or -1.
2. For each text pair , I want the features to be a concatenation in the following fashion:   f () = tfidf(t1) "concat" tfidf(t2)

Any suggestions on how to do the same ? I have the following code but it gives an error:

```
    count_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'char', ngram_range=ngram_range)
    X0_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform([x[0] for x in training_documents])
    X1_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform([x[1] for x in training_documents])
    combined_features = FeatureUnion([("x0", X0_train_counts), ("x1", X1_train_counts)])
    clf = LinearSVC().fit(combined_features, training_target)
    average_training_accuracy += clf.score(combined_features, training_target)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
scoreEdgesUsingClassifier(None, pos, neg, 1,ngram_range=(2,5), max_size=1000000, test_size=100000)

 scoreEdgesUsingClassifier(unc, pos, neg, number_of_iterations, ngram_range, max_size, test_size)
 X0_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform([x[0] for x in training_documents])
 X1_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform([x[1] for x in training_documents])
 combined_features = FeatureUnion([("x0", X0_train_counts), ("x1", X1_train_counts)])
 print "Done transforming, now training classifier"

lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in __init__(self, transformer_list, n_jobs, transformer_weights)
616         self.n_jobs = n_jobs
617         self.transformer_weights = transformer_weights
--> 618         self._validate_transformers()
619 
620     def get_params(self, deep=True):

lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.pyc in _validate_transformers(self)
660                 raise TypeError("All estimators should implement fit and "
661                                 "transform. '%s' (type %s) doesn't" %
--> 662                                 (t, type(t)))
663 
664     def _iter(self):

TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform. '  (0, 49025) 0.0575144797079

 (254741, 38401)    0.184394443164
 (254741, 201747)   0.186080393768
 (254741, 179231)   0.195062580945
 (254741, 156925)   0.211367771299
 (254741, 90026)    0.202458920022' (type <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>) doesn't
```

**Update**

Here's the solution:

```
    count_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=u'char', ngram_range=ngram_range)
    training_docs_combined = [x[0] for x in training_documents] + [x[1] for x in training_documents]        
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(training_docs_combined)
    concat_features  = hstack((X_train_counts[0:len(training_docs_combined) / 2 ], X_train_counts[len (training_docs_combined) / 2:]))

    clf = LinearSVC().fit(concat_features, training_target)
    average_training_accuracy += clf.score(concat_features, training_target)
```

Comment: The labels are for a pair of texts, not a single text? What error are you getting?

Comment: I put in the error.  ; Yes the labels are for a pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FeatureUnion` from scikit-learn takes as input estimators, not data arrays.

You can either concatenate the resulting `X0_train_counts`, `X1_train_counts` arrays simply with `scipy.sparse.hstack`, or create two independent instances of `TfidfVectorizer`, apply `FeatureUnion` to them, and then call the `fit_transform` method.

Comment: Thanks! hstack did the trick. I have updated the question with the solution.